# POST sending only partial data

Tags: php, apache, http, post, http-headers

I have a URL that I'm sending to a php backend using post. To rule out browser/javascript problems. I tried the request with cURL. Here's the request:

```
curl -X POST -F 'param1=something' -F 'param2=https://www.facebook.com/topic/NASA/103086076398533?source=whfrt&position=1&trqid=6308528345573812619' http://localhost/eng
```

The problem: Param2 is being only being recieved by php as `https://www.facebook.com/topic/NASA/103086076398533?source=whfrt&positi`

The even more weirder part is that if I move the word `position`, the position where the parameter gets cut at also moves so if i do:

```
curl -X POST -F 'param1=something' -F 'param2=https://www.facebook.com/?position=1&trqid=6308528345573812619' http://fe.ag/eng
```

The backend only receives `https //www.facebook.com/?positi`

- If I replace the word `position` in the parameter with any other word, the parameter is passed just fine.
- If I remove the character `n` in the word `position`, the parameter is passed just fine.
- These two mentioned behaviors persist even with the data string of param2, which is a url, is url encoded then passed.

I'm using lamp with Apache/2.4.18 in a XAMPP 5.6.3 installation.

Comment: Are you try url_encode first?

Comment: You may have an invalid character. Try pasting the entire curl command into a plain text editor like Gedit or Kate and copy / paste back to the shell.

Comment: Yes I'm encoding first.

Comment: @marekful I tried that already.